# Loop : How to know if last row not return 3 item per-row

Tags: php, for-loop

Below is code for loop and will show 3 items for each rows. But how to know if last row not return 3 item per-row but return 1 or 2 ? Because i want to echo `$x` in last row to make sure the last row will show at least 3 item including `[ item - ads]`.

```
$x = '[ item - ads]';

for ($i=1;$i<11;$i++) {

    echo ' [ item '.$i.'] ';

    $e = $i / 3;
    if (is_int($e)) {
        echo " - Rows $e ";
        echo '</br>';

    }
}
```

Result :

```
[ item 1] [ item 2] [ item 3] - Rows 1
[ item 4] [ item 5] [ item 6] - Rows 2
[ item 7] [ item 8] [ item 9] - Rows 3
[ item 10]
```

the result should be like this :

```
[ item 1] [ item 2] [ item 3] - Rows 1
[ item 4] [ item 5] [ item 6] - Rows 2
[ item 7] [ item 8] [ item 9] - Rows 3
[ item 10] [ item - ads] [ item - ads]
```

Comment: `But how to know if last row not return 3 item per-row but return 1 or 2 ?` - What does that mean? Please clarify.

Comment: @AmalMurali : Because i want to echo `$x` in last row to make sure the last row will show at least 3 item including `[ item - ads]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question without just providing working code:

```
$remainder = $total % 3;
```

For example:

```
$remainder = 10 % 3;
echo $remainder;
// returns 1
```

The percentage sign (or [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)) returns the remainder from deviding by 3.

Following up on that, you can try an approach like:

```
$numberOfAds = 3 - ($total % 3);
```